# How to get link specific php varaible to pass through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hyperlink

I dont know much about ajax or jquery yet  but i currently have an ajax script that does successfully send A variable through and does work properly.

--**the way i have it set up is like this for my loop:**

```
<?php  

$tt= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM monsters");

while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($tt))
{
$namee= $row['name'];

echo "<a id='namee' onclick='post();'>$namee</a>", "</br>";
}
```

which echos:

```
    horseman
    dragon
```

---the results do make a list of all the names from the table as shown above and they are clickable  which is working great

**my ajax request is this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function post(){

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "mess.php";
var vars =document.getElementById("namee").innerHTML;

hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
  document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = return_data;
  }
}

hr.send(vars);     // Actually execute the request  

alert(vars); 
 }


  </script>
```

the alert when i click on horseman returns "horseman"
but when i click on dragon  it still alerts "horseman"

i would like to get the specific variable  ( when i click horseman it says horseman and when i click dragon it says dragon etc) so i can send it through ajax to update a database ( which i already know to to set up)

please help me and show me if you can  full code so i can learn and see how it works and understand your response since im new like i said :)

thanks in advance:
if have any questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Thats because ids should be unique, jquery will get only the first element with that id, my suggestion is to pass the value by parameter:

```
echo "<a class='namee' onclick='post($namee);'>$namee</a>", "</br>";
```

And then the js:

```
function post(vars) {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "mess.php";
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request  
    alert(vars);
}
```